# Kafka Producer Stop sending message after certain amount of messages sent

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

My producer stops sending the message after 14116 messages have been sent. I have adjusted the number of `nofile` from the default value to 1048576.

After around four five minutes, the producer starts to send the message again, but then it stops at 21880 messages again ...

I am so confused here, I don't know where the problem could be ... any idea guys?

Please refer to the code below for more details.

````
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer011;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;

public class KafkaCreateData extends Thread {

    public static final String topic = "web_access";
    public static String bootstrap_servers = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx:9092";
    public static String zookeeper_connect = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx:2181";
    public static int msg_sent_count = 0;
    public static int userId = 0;

    public static void createData() {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            //EC2(Kafka producer IP here)
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers);
            props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper_connect);
            props.put("group.id", "metric-group");
            props.put("batch.size", 32768);
            props.put("buffer.memory", 67108864);
            props.put("send.buffer.bytes", 67108864);
            props.put("receive.buffer.bytes", -1);
//            props.put("max.block.ms", 1);
//            props.put("linger.ms", 1);
//            props.put("request.timeout.ms", 1);
//            props.put("delivery.timeout.ms", 5);
            props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"); //Key serialization
            props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"); //value serialization
            props.put("request.required.acks", "0");

            KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
            //phone brand
            String phoneArray[] = {"iPhone", "htc", "google", "xiaomi", "huawei"};
            //os
            String onlineArray[] = {"y", "n"};
            //city
            String cityArray[] = {"Taipei","Hong Kong","London","Paris","Tokyo","New York","Singapore","Rome"};
            //Generate Brand dandomly
            int k = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            String phoneName = phoneArray[k];
            //Generate os randomly
            int m = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
            String online = onlineArray[m];
            //Generate City randomly
            int n = (int) (Math.random() * 8);
            String city = cityArray[n];
            //Event Time Stamp
            SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss");
            Date date = new Date();
            String loginTime = sf.format(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
//            String user_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        //Loading Data into Entity
            entity.setCity(city);
            entity.setLoginTime(loginTime);
            entity.setOnline(online);
            entity.setPhoneName(phoneName);
            userId = userId + 1;
            entity.setuserId(userId);
            ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic,JSON.toJSONString(entity));
            producer.send(record);
            System.out.println("sending message："+ JSON.toJSONString(entity));
            msg_sent_count = msg_sent_count + 1;
            System.out.println("msg_sent_count: " + msg_sent_count);
    }

    public static void flink_streaming_job() throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers);
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeper_connect);
        props.put("group.id", "metric-group");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        System.out.println("Before addSource");
        env.addSource(
                new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<>(
                        topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), props
                )
//                        .setStartFromLatest()
        )
//                .setParallelism(9)
                .map(string -> JSON.parseObject(string, Entity.class))
                .addSink(new MysqlSink());
        System.out.println("before execute");
        env.execute("Flink add sink");
        System.out.println("start to execute");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            createTheData();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void createTheData() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
                createData();
                Thread.sleep(1); // if this setup as 1, broker will be broken, setup as 500 to ensure it can works
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        KafkaCreateData ConsumingMsgFromKafkaProducer = new KafkaCreateData();
        ConsumingMsgFromKafkaProducer.start();
        createData();

//        Flink job on EMR
//        flink_streaming_job();
    }
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qVTW.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F59am.png
````

Comment: Try reconfiguring ur batch.size = 10000 configuration.

Comment: @FatemaSagar Still got no luck here ...

Comment: it still stops at 14116 messages

Comment: In ur consumer try setting fetch.min.bytes.

Comment: I set fetch.min.bytes=67108864 in config/consumer.properties, it still stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment yet, can you try following approaches:

1. Create only one Producer: currently you create a producer each time you send a message which is not a best practice, and KafkaProducer is thread-safe so your program should need only one producer instance for given key-value and broker

Comment: It's working perfectly well. Thanks a lot! So the code I used, does that mean the maximum connection the broker can have from a particular instance is 14116? or it means that the maximum producer (thread) an instance can generate?

Comment: @JimmyHuang not sure yet, trying to run on my machine but got only 2016 before get `IOException: Too many open files` though I increate maxfiles, will try to look more into it

Comment: I was stuck at around 2k before, then I ran the command `sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf`, and change the nofile to 1048576. I think 1048576 is the upper limit of open file numbers? no sure the exact number for your machine. Save the file and reboot the machine, then you can excess 2k I think